# Error de indentación con la sentencia "else" en python

Tags: python

la idea de mi código es crear una lista con todos los divisores de un número, y si este número no tiene divisores, imprimir un mensaje. Pude hacer el código con la lista pero no logro configurarlo de manera tal que imprima el mensaje en caso un número primo, mi problema es en cuanto a la sentencia "else". Me pueden ayudar por favor?

```
def divisors(integer):
   list=[]
   for i in range(2,integer):
       if integer%i==0:
           list.append(i)
   return list
       else:
           return "prime num"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si una sentencia `return` es ejecutada la función termina en ese punto. Tu función después de salir del `for` siempre retorna la lista, esté o no vacía. Si quieres que retorne algo distinto cuando la lista esté vacía puedes simplemente usar un `or`. Esto es posible ya que una lista vacía es evaluada como `False`:

```
def divisors(integer):
   divs_list = []
   for i in range(2, integer):
       if integer %i == 0:
           divs_list.append(i)
   return divs_list or "prime num"
```

Otra opción es usar otro condicional:

```
def divisors(integer):
   divs_list = []
   for i in range(2, integer):
       if integer %i == 0:
           divs_list.append(i)

   if divs_list:
       return divs_list
   return "prime num"
```

O lo mismo pero usando el operador ternario:

```
def divisors(integer):
   divs_list = []
   for i in range(2, integer):
       if integer %i == 0:
           divs_list.append(i)
   return divs_list if divs_list else "prime num"
```

> **Nota:** `list` es una clase (un tipo de secuncia) en Python, no deberías usar ese nombre para nombrar una variable propia, sobreescribirla puede ser peligroso o como mínimo confuso. Usa otro nombre más descriptivo, o en todo caso puedes seguir las convenciones al respecto y nombrarla como `list_` .

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me fue muy útil esa corrección con el "or" y también muy útil la nota.

Comment: @Felka98, recuerda dar por aceptada la respuesta que te haya servido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error aquí es que el `return` debe ser al final de tu código cuando ya se haya terminado. La forma correcta de poner tu código seria:

```
def divisors(integer):
   list=[]
   for i in range(2,integer):
       if integer%i==0:
           list.append(i)
   if not list:
       return list
   else:
       return "prime num"
```

En este caso, cada que encuentre un numero divisible lo agregara a la lista, de lo contrario la lista permanecerá vacía, y al terminar de recorrer la todos los números (el ciclo for) se utiliza un if para evaluar si la lista se encuentra vacía o no, en caso de no estar vacía se retorna la lista, de lo contrario se retorna un `"prime num"`